# Test React component that depends on a Promise with Jest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise, jestjs, fetch

I'm trying to learn a bit more about JS tests.

I've got a basic React component that `fetch()`'s data when it mounts.

When running the app, the component works as expected and gets the data.

However when testing with Jest, I can see that the call has been made but the promise is always rejected?

I've been following [this example](https://medium.com/@rishabhsrao/mocking-and-testing-fetch-with-jest-c4d670e2e167) to produce the tests below.

Not sure about mocking promises with Jest, any pointers would be a huge help!

#### Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import * as Utils from './Functions';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Loader from './components/Loader';
import Table from './components/Table';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    /*
    Initialise state:
      # Loading: true
    */
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  /*
    When component mounts, 
    # Call function to get data
    # Set state with promise response
  */
  componentDidMount = () => {
    /* Function to grab data
      I've created a local express server to get around the cors issue
    */
    Utils.initData('http://localhost:8888/mock/all').then(data => {
      // Finally set state to reload component with new data
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        teams: data,
      })
    })
  }  

  render() {
    const { loading, teams } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <Header />
        <div className="table">
          {loading && (<Loader />)}
          {!loading && (<Table data={teams} loading={loading} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Functions

```js
export const initData = (dataURL) => {
  try {
    // Get data using the Fetch API
    return fetch(dataURL).then(
      response => response.json()
    )
      // Then sanitize the data
      .then(data => sanitizeData(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    return error;
  }
}
export const sanitizeData = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
  // Do loads of stuff with the data
}
```

#### Test

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';
import Table from './components/Table';
import Header from './components/Header';
import * as Utils from './Functions';

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('App', () => {
  it('- Renders the header', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Header />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });

  it('- Renders the table', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Table />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });

  it('- Renders the full app', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});

describe('Gets data', () => {
  it('fetches data from server when server returns a successful response', () => {
    const mockSuccessResponse = {};
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
    const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
      json: () => mockJsonPromise,
    });
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise); // 4
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);                      
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:8888/mock/all');
  });
});
```

#### Error messages

I don't get any error in the app itself but while the test runs I get:

```
(node:4082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
[1] (node:4082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[1] (node:4082) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The forEach mentioned above is from the `sanitizeData()` function and is there because the `data` param is `{}` when testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `{}` in mockJsonPromise which gets passed on to `sanitizeData()` add hence the `forEach` loop is not working. Return a list with mock data instead.

```
    const mockSuccessResponse = {};
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
    const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
      json: () => mockJsonPromise,
    });
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);
```

According to the above code `response.json()` will resolve to `mockSuccessResponse` which is `{}`